# Who is the Mighty Mormammu?

Tags: marvel, comics, doctor-strange

In Strange Tales #118 and then once again in the very next book, we come across Dr. Strange invoking the name of an entity called Mormammu. I initially thought that this was a typo, but then I remembered, Dormammu is usually mentioned as Dread Dormammu and never as Mighty (to the best of my knowledge).

What and who is Mormammu? Was that a typo or was that an entity that was dropped later by the authors?

Comment: I think it was in #119. And since it appeared only one time (and only one page of this issue to be specific), it is most likely a typo. Just like Bruce Banner was called Bob, Peter Parker was called Peter Palmer, and Spider-Man was called Superman.

Comment: @justanotherguy The best way to dispute someone else's recollection is to provide sources. :)

Comment: According to [Marvel fandom](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Strange_Tales_Vol_1_118) "Mormammu" appears in #118, but it links the name to the Dormammu page, so they consider it to be an alternate name; it's listed as an alternate on the [Dormammu page](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dormammu_(Earth-616)) with a [sole reference to issue #118](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dormammu_(Earth-616)#cite_note-Strange_Tales_Vol_1_118-3)

Comment: Strange invokes _"Mighty Mormammu"_ in #118, and then just _"Mormammu"_ in #119. Baron Mordo invokes _"Mighty Dormammu"_ in #117.

Comment: Mormammu? _LESS_-mammu more like 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's probably a typo. Probably...

In [Strange Tales 119](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYqZHk349uw) Dr. Strange needs to enter the [Purple Veil](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Purple_Veil_(Dimension)) to save two crooks who tried to steal a gem that was the doorway to that dimension. So he calls his Mormammu to help him

[image: Mormammu]

[This blog](https://cokeandcomics.com/strange-tales-118-story-b/#more-4848) about *Strange Tales 118* suggests it's a typo

> When he said Mormammu, I think he meant Dormammu. In fact, the Marvel Masterworks reprinting changes the text to read “Dormammu”. “Mormammu” was perhaps a typo. Or maybe Dr. Strange messed up the invocation, which probably would anger Dormammu.

And again about [Strange Tales 119](https://cokeandcomics.com/strange-tales-119-story-b/#more-5209)

> One confusing thing about the invocations is Mormammu vs. Dormammu. In this comic, he refers to both. The Marvel Masterworks I am reading changes all instances of “Mormammu” to “Dormmamu”, so I am sometimes uncertain which was used originally.
>
> I have two other reprints of this story, which disagree with each other. Giant-Size Defenders #2 kept the first reference as Mormammu. Marvel Collectors’ Item Classics #9 changed the first reference Dormammu. The second reference is definitely to Dormammu. In order, the below pictures are from the original comic, Marvel Collectors’ Item Classics #9 (1967), and Giant-Size Defenders #2 (1974).

And indeed, they have this version from a later reprint (panel #3 from the previous strip) that has it as Dormammu. Yet another later printing after that went back to Mormammu

[image: Dormammu?]

So... is it a typo, or was it intentional? The original Stan Lee work has it as Mormammu. Someone at Marvel thought it was a typo and "fixed" it, but someone else put it back to the original. Since this is the only time it's ever really used, it strongly suggests a typo, but the story itself about the Purple Dimension is a one-off and Strange does not go there again.

Comment: Don't forget Stan Lee and his love for words starting with the same letter. So Mighty Mormammu might not have been a typo...

Comment: @justanotherguy - Don't forget that Stan's memory wasn't the best in regard to names, and that the reason he liked to give characters alliterative names is so that if he could remember a character's first or last name, he'd have a built-in clue that'd help him to recall the other one. Even then, he still got names wrong on occasion, having narrative captions twice refer to Peter Parker as "Peter Palmer" in _Amazing Spider-Man #1_, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is dated, but neither Stan Lee or Ditko never addressed this. So we can only surmise that since Dormammu had not been mentioned again until ST #120, that Mormammu may have been a different entity?  Strange referred to him as "Mighty Mormammu", but referred to Dormammu as "The Dread Dormammu".

I know it appears nuance, but it's all we have to go on.

[image: ST #120 Strange cleansing a possessed house]

Comment: Good point about the different alliterative qualifier used.

Comment: As I noted in a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263810/who-is-the-mighty-mormammu#comment727121_263810) beneath the question, Baron Mordo invokes "Mighty Dormammu" in _Strange Tales #117_. As Shreedhar noted in [another comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263810/who-is-the-mighty-mormammu#comment727113_263810), Stan was also known for occasionally getting characters' names wrong, having Dr. Octopus refer to Spider-Man as "Super-Man" in _Amazing Spider-Man #3_, to name one particularly egregious example.